# Kendo numeric box (mvc) did not work properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

> I have a kendo numeric text box, but it does not work properly.
>
> First time it work and look like it,

[image: First time it works]

> After do some operation (post back) then it look like it,

[image: After]

> Please help me out.